# opening infowindow on button click in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

i am calling a function **fxn** with a parameter marker but i am not able to retrive its value in function definition
like it id but i need to open a infowindow on that click
need to  open infowindow on button or div click which is already done but having an error

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "empty/GovtEmp.aspx",
            success: function(data) {
                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                var ary = data.split(",");
                mycenter = new google.maps.LatLng(24.6510734558105, 46.7010765075684);
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: mycenter,
                    zoom: 4,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
                for (i = 0; i < obj.POI.length; i++) {
                    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.POI[i].Latitude, obj.POI[i].Longitude);
                  var  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: location,
                        id: obj.POI[i].Poi_Id,
                        html:   "dataaaaaaaaa",
                        map: map
                    });
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
                        po = 1;
                        $(".AdsDivLeft").css("color", "black");
                        $(".AdsDivLeft").css("background-color", "white");
                        $("#divLft" + this.id).css("color", "green");
                        $("#divLft" + this.id).css("background-color", "yellow");
                        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(event) {
                        //$("#divLft" + POI[i].Poi_Id).css("color", "black");
                        po = 0;
                        $("#divLft" + this.id).css("color", "green");
                        $("#divLft" + this.id).css("background-color", "yellow");
                        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function(event) {
                        if (po == 0) {
                            $(".AdsDivLeft").css("color", "black");
                            $(".AdsDivLeft").css("background-color", "white");
                            infowindow.close(this.html);
                        }
                    });
                    divPan = document.createElement("div");
                    divPan.id = "divLft" + k;
                    divPan.className = "AdsDivLeft";
                    divPan.style.border = "groove 5px #FDFDFD";
                    divPan.innerHTML = "<div style=\"border:solid 2px red;\" onclick='fxn(\"" + marker + "\")'>Click</div>";
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function fxn(mrkr) {

        alert(mrkr.id);
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infowindow.setContent(mrkr.html);
        infowindow.open(map, mrkr);
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?  Where are you getting the argument to the function from?  Is it a google.maps.Marker object?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the issue is here:

```
divPan.innerHTML = "<div style=\"border:solid 2px red;\" onclick='fxn(\"" + marker + "\")'>Click</div>";
```

In particular, having marker there doesn't magically embed the marker in the html. If you're embedding Javascript in HTML it can only be text. You can't magically have objects (such as marker) be included. What's actually going on here is string concatenation using some string representation of the object marker

Well actually you can magically embed an object, just not the way you did. The way to magically have an object be associated with this Javascript function embedded in the HTML is to use a closure. If you're not familiar with closures, do a web search for it. The end result will look something like this (not tested or anything):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "empty/GovtEmp.aspx",
        success: function(data) {
            obj = JSON.parse(data);
            var ary = data.split(",");
            mycenter = new google.maps.LatLng(24.6510734558105, 46.7010765075684);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: mycenter,
                zoom: 4,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
            for (i = 0; i < obj.POI.length; i++) {
                var location = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.POI[i].Latitude, obj.POI[i].Longitude);
              var  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    id: obj.POI[i].Poi_Id,
                    html:   "dataaaaaaaaa",
                    map: map
                });
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
                    po = 1;
                    $(".AdsDivLeft").css("color", "black");
                    $(".AdsDivLeft").css("background-color", "white");
                    $("#divLft" + this.id).css("color", "green");
                    $("#divLft" + this.id).css("background-color", "yellow");
                    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(event) {
                    //$("#divLft" + POI[i].Poi_Id).css("color", "black");
                    po = 0;
                    $("#divLft" + this.id).css("color", "green");
                    $("#divLft" + this.id).css("background-color", "yellow");
                    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function(event) {
                    if (po == 0) {
                        $(".AdsDivLeft").css("color", "black");
                        $(".AdsDivLeft").css("background-color", "white");
                        infowindow.close(this.html);
                    }
                });
                divPan = document.createElement("div");
                divPan.id = "divLft" + k;
                divPan.className = "AdsDivLeft";
                divPan.style.border = "groove 5px #FDFDFD";
                fxn = create_fxn(marker); // Creates a global variable since didn't use var keyword
                divPan.innerHTML = "<div style=\"border:solid 2px red;\" onclick='fxn()'>Click</div>"; // When fxn() is called here, the object marker is known to it because a closure was used.
            }
        }
    });
});

function create_fxn(mrkr) { // This function is a closure since it returns a function that has mrkr enclosed or embedded within it.

    return function(){

        alert(mrkr.id);
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infowindow.setContent(mrkr.html);
        infowindow.open(map, mrkr);
    }
}
```

Note that this will only work for one info window though: there's only one global object by the name of fxn. So if you call create_fxn a second time, you'll be overwritting fxn. If you need to support multiple windows, you'll a way to keep track of them and include your different fxn's (created with create_fxn) in a list or something.

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing anywhere in the code where you actually append the `div` you're creating to the DOM, so I would add the following after you set the `innerHTML`: `document.body.appendChild(divPan);`